Compare Dates of String Type
I want to update the field IsStudent based on condition. In c# driver builder is not working and i want to keep date in string.
Collection: Student
Field: IsStudent
var filter = Builder<Student>.Filter.Gt(t => t.lastDay, FirstDay);
var updateuilder = Builder<Student>.Update.Set(t => t.IsStudent, "N");

Format of lastDay = "20240125000000000"
format of FirstDay = "20210615"
Please suggest how should I compare the dates in builder to update.

why do you want to store the dates as string? Is there any particular reason for that? Cause this makes it harder to compare the dates.

"is not working" is not enough of a problem description. Is it giving you compiler-errors, runtime errors / exceptions, is it not doing what you expect it to do, ...?

I do not get any error, it just does not update IsStudent to "N" based on the filter condition. And all the fields in Collection are stored as string.

You just defined a filter and and an update but you didn't use them. You must use both against a MongoDB Collection. For example via UpdateMany.

You need to handle the string-based date comparison carefully since MongoDB treats strings as lexicographical values rather than actual dates. Here's how you can do it:

Make sure the date strings are in a comparable format (e.g., yyyyMMdd).


Also use  the Builders<T> syntax to construct the filter and update.

Your code should look this way:
var filter = Builders<Student>.Filter.Gt(t => t.lastDay, "20210615");
var update = Builders<Student>.Update.Set(t => t.IsStudent, "N");

// Perform the update operation
await studentCollection.UpdateManyAsync(filter, update);

